# How can I click this option with Python+selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I click “Actions“ option with Python+selenium? I have tried a lot of methods, please help me with some suggestions, thank you.

**The following methods do not work：**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id="tabGroup_tabtable"]/tbody/tr/td[2]").click()
```

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#tabGroup_tabtable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)").click()
```

```html
<table id="tabGroup_tabtable" class="tabGroup_tabtable">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td onclick="setFullHelpID(HelpLinks.EDITOR_COMPUTEROVERVIEW);tabGroupSetSelected(0);resize();" tabindex="0" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode==13||event.keyCode==32) {tabGroupSetSelected(0);resize();}" class="tab_selected">
        <div class="tab_name">General</div>
      </td>

      <td onclick="setFullHelpID(HelpLinks.EDITOR_COMPUTEROVERVIEW_ACTIONS);tabGroupSetSelected(1);resize();" tabindex="0" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode==13||event.keyCode==32) {tabGroupSetSelected(1);resize();}" class="tab" onmouseover="this.className='tab_over';"
        onmouseout="this.className='tab';">
        <div class="tab_name">Actions</div>
      </td>


      <td onclick="setFullHelpID();tabGroupSetSelected(2);loadEvents();" tabindex="0" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode==13||event.keyCode==32) {tabGroupSetSelected(2);loadEvents();}" class="tab" onmouseover="this.className='tab_over';" onmouseout="this.className='tab';">
        <div class="tab_name">System Events</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error or exception

Comment: You need to provide the url to help you. Maybe `driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tab")[0].click()` would work but without testing i cannot help

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I have already solved it.
since my page is in the frame, I need to switch to the framework first using driver.switch_to.frame("input your frame name").